# Tags with or : Or do I ? Is it always proper english?

Tags: question-tags

I often see sentences with the structure

> Girls just wanna have fun, *or do they*?

I know that with tags, the modal is supposed to be affirmative if the phrase was negative, and negative if the contrary. For example, *I think it's true, don't you?*

But with respect to *or are they?*, it translates something else, a kind of purposefully induced suspicion. Would they? No, really, they don't. And I never see (or hear, and it does not sound right) *Girls just wanna have fun, or doesn't they?* So is it actually correct to always use *or are/do/can/should/etc. they?* and not their negative forms?

Comment: The usual tag in your example would be "don't they?"

Comment: It is perfectly correct, yes. The real question is whether “Or do they?” is a tag question. I would say it isn’t. Similarly, in your other example, “I think it’s true, don’t you?”, there is no tag question. “Don’t you?” is a separate question. “You think it’s true, don’t you?” has a tag question, as does “Girls just wanna have fun, don’t they?”. But the others you mentioned are not.

Comment: A tag is a tag because it is "stuck" to the verb, isn't it? Or isn't it? [Or Isn't it here is not a tag]. You think it's true, don't you? It is a tag question, because tag questions use the main verb of the sentence, don't they?

Comment: [*Us Brits are on top of this one, **innit?***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5MFpHz1Mj8) Conjugating tag questions is *so* last century.

Comment: @Lambie I think the examples in your comment befuddled more than they illuminated there. I’m not sure, for example, what the intention behind “It is a tag question, because tag questions use the main verb of the sentence, don’t they?” was, since tag questions frequently (as in your example) **don’t** use the main verb of the sentence, but a pro-verb.

Comment: A tag question has to have the tag right after the verb. That is all I meant. So, I made a joke of it. Here's the tag question:  
A tag is a tag because it is "stuck" to the verb, isn't it? Whereas adding /Or isn't it?/ as a separate utterance after the main utterance is not an example of a tag question. Yes, all innits are tags. [that too is a joke, not great, I admit].

Comment: @BillJ But it's not a tag, it's a coordinate  in a coordination of finite clauses.

Comment: As Lambie correctly points out, "or do they? is not a question tag. It is just an interrogative clause functioning as a coordinate in a coordination of finite clauses. A tag would be "Girls just wanna have fun, do they?", which is quite different.